# Android : XmlSerializer or FastXmlSerializer writes &amp; for &

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-xml, android-xmlpullparser

In android, when writing some values containing '&' in the text part, FastXmlSerializer.attribute() or  Xml.newSerializer().attribute(), method encodes '&' as '&amp ;'. Is there any other Xml serializer or the property that must be set to write '&' as it is in xml data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`&` in XML must always be escaped as `&amp;`, otherwise the XML will be invalid. Do you really want to write invalid XML?